# Issues implementing EFI Grub in USB install of Lubuntu to allow usage with both Legacy and UEFI boot configurations

Tags: boot, grub2, lubuntu, uefi, grub-efi

https://askubuntu.com/a/1253617/1098871 is the link to the process I followed.

At step 42 I get an error,

```
grub-install: error: /boot/efi doesn't look like an EFI partition.
```

Screenshot
[image: error message]
Help me out with what I should do from here , I'm clueless !

@C.S.Cameron @Ravexina

Comment: UEFI install defaults to first drive. Ubuntu's Ubiquity only installs to first drive. So if you do not have an ESP on first drive it will fail. But if you specify a different drive with grub install or have an ESP specified in fstab then it will use that ESP.

Answer (score 0):

After much fretting, I got a working solution. The solution would be to simple type in `sudo mount /dev/sdx2 /boot/efi` before attempting to install grub.

A more detailed guide including Daniel's guide and some additions by me for adding drivers for Macs and Nvidia GPUs as well as useful generalisation to apply to any distribution of Linux :

https://docs.google.com/document/d/14PWThtbylgmqsnQbR8hUbgU6hfh55GJ9N1EOEEbrnzg/edit?usp=sharing

The document mentioned above is written with 3 purposes:

1. Allow you to make your portable, full-fledged Linux install that will, ideally, work on any x86 PC that you wish to boot from.
2. Achieve the 1st objective , ideally, on any distro.
3. Allow a complete noob to follow instructions and links to achieve the 1st and 2nd objective.